# workaround for getting multiple values from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, subquery

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT c.*, CAST ( 0 as int ) Score 
FROM Caregiver c JOIN Elderly e ON EXISTS 
( 
 SELECT x.LanguageID FROM 
 ( 
  SELECT 1 AS LanguageID WHERE e.Chinese = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS LanguageID WHERE e.Malay = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS LanguageID WHERE e.Tamil = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS LanguageID WHERE e.English = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 AS LanguageID WHERE e.Others = 1
 ) 
 x INTERSECT SELECT y.LanguageID FROM 
 ( 
  SELECT 1 AS LanguageID WHERE c.Chinese = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS LanguageID WHERE c.Malay = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3 AS LanguageID WHERE c.Tamil = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4 AS LanguageID WHERE c.English = 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5 AS LanguageID WHERE c.Others = 1
 ) 
 y 
) 
WHERE e.NRIC=@nric2 
AND c.CaregiverID != (SELECT CaregiverID FROM RequestPairing WHERE ReqID=@reqid2)
```

which does not work because the subquery `( SELECT CaregiverID FROM RequestPairing WHERE ReqID=@reqid2)` is returning multiple values.

My intention is to make use of the subquery to exclude certain rows from being returned by the main query.

So any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this condition to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE e.NRIC=@nric2 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT CaregiverID FROM RequestPairing 
WHERE ReqID=@reqid2 AND CaregiverID = c.CaregiverID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `not in`:

```
WHERE e.NRIC=@nric2 and
      c.CaregiverID not in (SELECT CaregiverID FROM RequestPairing WHERE ReqID=@reqid2)
```

Comment: thx, both `not in` and `not exists` works but i am going with `not exists` because the performance is apparently better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Instead of `!=`, you can use `NOT IN` with parentheses around the select query.